# unabled to set the seleted value on a combo box

Tags: jsp

Sir, I have a combobox whose values are loaded from the database. My combobox coding is as follows

```
<select name="type" size="1" id="type" align="left">

     <%
         Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
         Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/online_exam?"+"user=root&password=pass");
         Statement stmt1=con.createStatement();
         ResultSet rs1=stmt1.executeQuery("select * from course");
         String courseid,crsname;

         while(rs1.next()){
                 courseid=rs1.getString(1);


         %>
         <option value=""><%=courseid%></option>
         <%}%>
</select>
```

when I run my project values are loaded into the combobox but I am unabled to select a particular value from the combobox. The value remains same with the first value of the combobox. Can u kindly say me where is the prblem?