# unabled to keep selected value in a combo box

Tags: jsp

Sir,

Im trying to implement the search feature in my website.

when i select a value into the combobox, the form will be Posted and the result will be shown on the same page.But after the response comes from the servlet, the default value is displayed into the combobox.
 i want is to keep the selected category of the combo by default in the form after posted

For eg.,the combobox default value is'C001'and If i select the 'C008' in the combo and click search, after form submit, the combo should show 'C008' as default selected option. Please help me. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Do not repost the same question over and over. This is a duplicate of [unabled to set the seleted value on a combo box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5935225/unabled-to-set-the-seleted-value-on-a-combo-box)

Comment: @BalusC: it seems like same question. I've edited the previous question but didn't remembered... ;-p

Comment: Re-asking the same question isn't acceptable behavior here.  If you want to draw attention to your question, you will be allowed to [place a bounty on it](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty) after two days.  You can also [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5936710/edit) to add additional information, which may make your question easier to understand and answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should use AJAX. This way the page will be not reloaded and value in combo box will not change.

---

in js:

```
function callThisOnchangeOfComboBox(){

        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        xmlhttp.open("POST", urlOfServlet, false);
        xmlhttp.send(null);
        //----------- parse xmlhttp.responseText as you need. 
}
```

Comment: can you please give an example how to use ajax in this case

Comment: sir my servlet is in a Java package named DBCon and servlet name is searchCourseName.do. For this i am writing the url of servlet as follows   "DBCon/searchCourseName.do". But it is not working. Can you please say where is the problem?

Comment: @Kanika: use same url as you have declare for your servlet in web.xml. It will be something like `<url-pattern>/UrlServlet</url-pattern>`

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to pass the "selected" tag to the correct option as follow:

`<option value="" selected>`

You could check the value within your while loop and put the "selected" string when appropiate.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <option value='<%=courseId%>' selected="selected"><%=courseId%></option>
```